# Is it possible to generate column names for a my SQL table dynamically from xml data?

Tags: mysql, xml

I mean to say that I want attribute names as column names followed by values
And data is like this (small portion)

```
<row _id="1" _uuid="0BEBAB70-5985-4A1C-862F-A842BF7F293C" _position="1" _address="http://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/_6rqk-pdub/1">
<full_name>Aarhus, Pam J.</full_name><gender>F</gender><current_annual_salary>68878.16</current_annual_salary><_2015_gross_pay_received>72336.79</_2015_gross_pay_received>
<department>POL</department><department_name>Department of Police</department_name>
<division>MSB Information Management and Technology Division Data Systems Section</division><assignment_category>Fulltime-Regular</assignment_category>
<position_title>Office Services Coordinator</position_title><date_first_hired>1986-09-22T00:00:00</date_first_hired></row>![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXqHe.jpg)
```

I need output as
 row I'd as one column
Full name as one column like that

Comment: So I understand that you have xml data and you need to put that data into mysql table. Is that right ?

Comment: Yeah I need a logic for making attribute names I.e rowid,fullname,gender .. as column names and values to be inserted in that columns

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN xml_data varchar)
BEGIN
    /* Put your logic and set your sql dynamic from xml_data */
    SET @sql = ...

    PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
END
```

Comment: Can u specify the logic